# Odoo v16e selected Partners break up on a customised report

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-domain

I'm customizing a report through configuration->Management->Accounting Reports and I need a breakup of a few specific partners' balances not all. I tried putting desired partner's Id into the domain but I get the error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'".

[My current settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXwAf.png)

Comment: Why is there a dot (`.`) after `partner_id`?

Comment: sorry, i was changing a lot of things and forgot to remove the dot before taking a screenshot. with [("partner_id", "=", 1)] it gives me this error
"AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'"